# Facebook Connect vs Zoo Visitor

Tags: zoo-visitor, solspace, facebook

I was wondering if someone has successfully implemented both Facebook Connect and Zoo Visitor on a single site. Are there any issues I should be aware of? Does creating an account through Facebook also trigger the creation of a Zoo Visitor member-channel entry? Client has requested a quote on this functionality and I don't want to promise something that's dead in the water before I've even started.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: I have no experience with Facebook Connect, but Social Login and Social Login Pro http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-login-pro are both compatible with Zoo Visitor, i.e. the record in Zoo Visitor channel is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steven, I would recommend using Yuri’s addon, Social Login PRO, if only for the fact that he and the EE Zoo team have worked to make them work well together. To that extent though, the documentation on ensuring a sync is a little sparse for my tastes. I do see this link: [Integration with Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/social-login-pro/viewthread/3805) that shows a bit about how to ensure the syncing isn’t a one-time deal, but as for making it happen with FBC, I’m not sure it’ll happen yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it on a site I worked on a while back. My memory isn't fresh, since it's been handed off to the client and my hands are completely off it, but I can tell you that it does work — it's just a bit tricky.

As powerful and awesome as Zoo Visitor is, you have to remember that you are basically duplicating data from EE's native member database into its own channel, and therefore when a user is created via alternate means (like Facebook Connect), you have to then ensure that the user also gets a new entry in the Zoo Visitor channel.

It sounds simple now, but you just have to invoke Zoo Visitor's sync tag:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:sync}
```

…which frustratingly isn't mentioned in the official docs. I found out about it here:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/2395